# When writing documentation for web-technologies that use American spelling, should the text also use American spelling?

Tags: american-english, british-english, terminology, spelling

As we know, English exists in many dialects.

In another life, over 20 years ago, I spent a year and a half in Japan, teaching English. I was under no obligation to teach standard **American English** but I had no desire to mark my students exclusively on their grasp of standard **British English**, either.

So I did my best, whenever a discrepancy between the two emerged (in spelling or in common communicative phrases) to give my students both forms and recommend that they use whichever they were most comfortable with, but that they should endeavour to use either standard American or standard British ***on a consistent basis***.

Two decades later and I find myself writing technical documentation for web-technologies.

It seems to me that the web has its own dialect, *Web English*, which generally resembles American English but isn't (because it will be used as readily by Australian or British English speakers as by US English speakers).

Hence we have:

- `color`
- `background-color`
- `text-align: center`

But if we regard this as *Web English* (and I recognise that some will insist that it's not that - it's simply American English), should documentation *also* be written using *Web English*, to ***maintain consistency***?

Normally I write using British English terminology and British English spelling. But, to maintain consistency, is it recommended that I write technical documentation in the same *Web English* as my HTML / CSS / Javascript?

**E.g.**

- *you can define the element's **color** with the CSS property `color`*
- *you can define the element's **background color** with the CSS property `background-color`*
- *you can **center** the text by giving the CSS property `text-align` a value of `center`*

---

**Tangential question:**

If I do all that, what am I supposed to do with *"parentheses"*? Just use American English?

Comment: I am reminded of how we are all stuck with an HTTP header named **referer** because Phillip Hallam-Baker didn't know how to spell "referrer"...

Comment: Hah! I always thought that was an "in-joke" (like _Paamayim Nekudotayim_ or, better yet, _mod_speling_ in Apache `.htaccess`). Was it actually a spelling mistake? :o

Comment: I don't think technical terminology constitutes a "dialect". I wouldn't even call it English if I were to pick nits. That would be similar to saying "try-except-finally" structures in technical documentation should follow English grammar instead of the syntax of the programming language the documentation is about. The only reason it's background-color instead of background-colour is because that's what the specification of the language says it should be.

Comment: The property names are jargon and only incidentally english. In some other language, the property would still be `center` but the surrounding text would not. As an AmE speaker, I would think nothing was amiss when reading "use `center` to centre text."

Comment: @ColleenV So, in my documentation, are you saying I'll be fine if I write: _"you can define the element's background colour with the CSS property `background-color`"_?

Comment: @Rounin Absolutely. The spelling in the English text should be consistently BrE or AmE throughout, but computer language elements should be used as they are specified.

Comment: A more subtle example comes from AmE punctuation normally being placed inside what in technical documentation would be a string literal. Probably relates to parens handling.

Comment: @Rounin - According to what history I can find, "referer" was the spelling used in the original proposal to add the header, and nobody who saw it realized it was a misspelling, and it just got passed along until it was in a formal standards document.

Comment: Is this an English Language Learning question?  it would seem more at home at [english.se]

Comment: If CSS had been developed by the French and the names of the properties were things like `couleur` and `centrer`, would you feel the need to use French words in the description to match?  There's no reason that keywords have to be linguistically consistent with the descriptive text.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doens't address any language learning issue.  But I think it is on topic at [english.se]

Comment: I don't think it is a good question and I doubt ELU would appreciate it either. It's like asking "Is there science English?". All fields have their own lingo and knowledge....and none of it is "dialectal". Dialects don't exist at the level of technical writing unless the standard language is viewed as one.

Comment: CanadianYankee - Your question is fair, but I'd submit that choosing whether to use one language or another, is not the same is choosing whether to use one dialect or another of the _same language_, in a specific context. In London I will refer to the metropolitan underground railway as _the tube_. When I am in NYC I will refer to it as _the subway_. I am asking whether English Native Speakers _and_ **English Language Learners** should be recommended to use US-like English spelling and terminology in the context of discussing web technologies. @ColleenV has made the best counterpoint to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is such a thing as “Web English”, it’s definitely not what you are describing.

The entities in a computer language are not English. They may look like English words to make it easier for people to remember them, but they are syntactically distinct.

The `background-color` entity is no different than `declspec` or `__init__`. The only valid spelling of those identifiers is the spelling defined in the specification of the computer language. There’s no such thing as “Python English” even though the Python language has quite a few elements that look like English words.

Often, a book will list the typographical conventions it will use to help the reader distinguish code from English text. [The preface of Programming C# 8.0](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Programming_C_8_0/w07ADwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=conventions%20in%20this%20book%20c%23&pg=PR15&printsec=frontcover) is a good example.

Because ‘code’ is not English even though some parts of it might look like English words, it’s perfectly acceptable to use whichever spelling you prefer in the English text. “You can define the element's background **colour** with the CSS property `background-color`.” is correct if the rest of the text is using British spelling.